# Rails 3.1: Adding .scss stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

Just trying to get to grips with the new Rails 3.1 way of managing assets. I've copied across a .scss stylesheet (style.css.scss) to app/assets/stylesheets/, and added

```
= stylesheet_link_tag :style
```

To the app/views/layouts/application.html.haml file. I had expected that was all I needed to do - but no joy; scss doesn't seem to be generating the css sheet. When I view the 'style.css' source in page source (yes, it's called in the html source) it says the following:

> ## Routing Error
>
> ```
> No route matches [GET]
> "/assets/style.css"
> ```

So...any ideas how to get 3.1 to generate the actual stylesheet from the scss?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `style.css` file to your `assets/stylesheets/` directory that looks like this:

```
/*
 *= require style.css.scss
 */
```

That should automatically convert your `style.css.scss` to plain CSS and include it in what `/assets/style.css` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the problem you described was due to Rails 3.1 not being released yet, but the "standard" Rails 3.1 way would be to put *style.css.scss* in your *app/assets/stylesheets* folder and then linking to *application.css* which is a socalled manifest file that includes all other files from the folder.

You would then be using

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

instead.

Best regards,
Lasse